# c# call base constructor with ref parameter

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

Supposed there is a class in C# like this:

```
class A {
     public A(ref int value) {
          value = 1;
     }
}
```

Is it possible to derive this class?

Comment: Now why in the world would you need out/ref parameters for a constructor? The only thing that a constructor should produce is the object it is constructing. Using it this way is just fundamentally wrong.

Comment: It’s syntactically correct. ;)

Comment: It seems that asking questions is wrong. :(

Comment: @ominug here is a link you can find your answers and how to do things according to C# standards [C# Basics Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/index.htm)

Comment: asking questions is never wrong.. I think that when people ask questions in regards to `Over thinking` and or `trying to re-invent the wheel` or get smart in regards to how things operate and or function in a particular language because one may have done it that way in a previous object interpreted language vs Object Oriented language then push backs as well as feed back of this nature is kind of hard to resist..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can inherit from A and call the base constructor:

```
class B : A
{
    public B(ref int value): base(ref value)
    {
    }
}
```

But to be honest, it's the first time I see a constructor with ref/out parameters. Those parameters are used when the method is performing some calculations and modifying the value of the parameter which is not what a constructor should be doing. I would rather put this in a separate method.

Comment: Ok, but I need to entrain the parameter, isn’t that so?

Comment: Yes, the value will be passed in the chain of constructors.